# How to run a Java program behind a web app giving the web app access to it's objects?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jstl, real-time

I am currently building a java web app in netbeans.  I have come to a point where I am stuck now.  I have a draft application for a sports website I am building.  The draft has the ability to have every user in the league access it, but I need it to be synchronized for all of them.

I want to run a java program or method that will create the draft at the specified date and time, then have centralized variables and a timer that each user can access when they access the web page.

So I want every user to see the same thing when they open the draft, regardless of what point in time they open it.  Essentially this draft needs to run regardless of whether or not anyone actually opens it.

I am struggling with how I can do this, I was thinking threads, or a cron job, but I have no idea how to gain access to the program I run from my web app using something such as JSTL or jsp:useBean.

Any help at all would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there any reason why the data cannot be stored in database and accessed? That way everyone can see the same information, whatever is in the database.

Comment: It could and will be, but there is a list, the order of the draft, so for example, player1-player2-player3-player4-player4-players3-player2-player1...... Each player has an alotted time, say 20 seconds, to pick their player.  So whenever a user opens this draft page, they need to be synched with the current pick and the time left that player has.  So I want to have a clock running on the Java program that when the page opens, I make an ajax call and grab the current pick and time left for that pick.

Answer (score 1):

Since real-time consitency is important to your application.

One simple approach would be to store the draft information in database.

Set the sort order, start time and end time for all records in the database. Since you know this information before hand, you can do this from an admin script. Just run the admin script manually or at a preset time to update the database.

Now, clients can request the records that should be displayed given current time.

Added advantage with this procedure is that your client (JSP) can retrieve users in bunch with start time and end time and display them.

You don't have to make AJAX type of call every 20 seconds.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think I am being unclear though.  Basically when you open the draft, there is a counter displayed on the screen, that counts down from the time the user has to pick a player, to 0.  If the user does not pick, then a player is automatically picked for them.  But this timer needs to run, and users need to be able to see where it is in its countdown to the second.  So this Java applet needs to run the countdown, but there isn't a set end time.  If every user picks their players within 5 seconds, the draft will be much shorter.